# Python: extracted email address from a webpage returning extra characters

Tags: python, regex, email

[Here](https://viterbi.usc.edu/directory/faculty/Zadeh/Ali-Enayat) is the example web address that contains an email address.
Here is the code that I am using:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

url = 'https://viterbi.usc.edu/directory/faculty/Zadeh/Ali-Enayat'
page_response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, "html.parser")
email = re.findall(r"[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+@[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+\.[a-z]+", soup.text)
print(email)
```

I am expecting it to return `azadeh@usc.edu` as the email address but it returns `740-4694azadeh@usc.edu`. What am I doing wrong, and how this can be solved so the email extraction works for any webpage?

Comment: What is the logic that tells us there should be boundary between `740-4694` and `azadeh@usc.edu`?  We can't really help you without knowing this.

Comment: If I look at the page source I see: <br /><h6>Contact Information</h6><ul><li style="margin-left: 20px;">(213) 740-4694</li><li style="margin-left: 20px;">azadeh@usc.edu</li>
so clearly there is some boundary. Can this help?

Comment: Please _don't_ use regex to parse HTML, that's evil.  Use an HTML/XML parser instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use `re` when the full capabilities of `bs4` are at your disposal:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
d = soup(requests.get('https://viterbi.usc.edu/directory/faculty/Zadeh/Ali-Enayat').text, 'html.parser')
email = d.find('div', {'class':'contactInformation'}).find_all('ul')[-2].find_all('li')[-1].text
```

Output:

```
'azadeh@usc.edu'
```

Edit: a more generic approach is to apply the regular expression to the html content of the `bs4` object:

```
re.findall(r"[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+@[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+\.[a-z]+", str(d))
```

Output:

```
['azadeh@usc.edu']
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but not every page has a class called `contactInformation`. I was wondering if it can be done for any page that has an email address no matter what.

Comment: @TJ1 Can you provide a link to an example of a page without a `contactInformation` `div`?

Comment: @TJ1 This is a very broad problem, as it is indeed difficult to detect the boundaries between email addresses and other elements. I added a solution that applies `re.findall` to the *html* content of the `bs4` object, rather than the text, however, this is not overly robust in certain cases. An event better approach would be to find the finite set of university names you are working with, and then write a custom function to find the email on a page associated with that school. You could scrape the school name from the url, and add it to a dictionary with the corresponding method as its key.

Comment: Thanks, your edited response works at least for my case.